# how to implement the restore process for non renewable subscriptions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Anyone of you implement the restoration process for **non-renewable subscriptions**? if so, can you please tell me the process. in my application i am going to implement the restore.i have searched in more forum. but i can't able to get the ideas.

thanks advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no restoration process from Apple for non-renewable subscriptions.  You are responsible for implementing some method for restoration and making active subscriptions across a user's devices.

From the [In-App Purchasing Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH2-SW5)

> Non-renewing subscriptions differ from auto-renewable subscriptions in a few key ways. These differences give your app the flexibility to implement the correct behavior for your needs, as follows:
>
> - Your app is responsible for calculating the time period that the subscription is active and determining what content needs to be made available to the user.
> - Your app is responsible for detecting that a subscription is approaching its expiration date and prompting the user to renew the subscription by purchasing the product again.
> - Your app is responsible for making subscriptions available across all the user’s devices after they’re purchased and for letting users restore past purchases. For example, most subscriptions are provided by a server; your server would need some mechanism to identify users and associate subscription purchases with the user who purchased them.

Comment: how to get the receipt details after purchase has done with apple?

Comment: You get the purchase confirmation on your `SKPaymentQueue`; It is your job to then record the subscript status  & determine when the subscription will end.  If your app has a user account then you should update the subscription status on your server so that the user can access it on other devices where they are logged in.